# $\sin(\pi^2/ 4)$ appears as I try to solve $\int_{0}^{\pi\over2}x \sin (2x^2 ) \mathrm{dx}$

Tags: integration

$$  \begin{align}
A&:=\int_{0}^{\pi\over2}x \sin \left(2x^2 \right) \mathrm{dx}
\\\theta&:=x^2\\
x&:~ 0\to{\pi\over2}\\
\theta&:~ 0\to{\pi^2\over4}\\
{\mathrm{d \theta} \over \mathrm{dx} }&=2x \iff  {\mathrm{ d\theta}\over2} =x \mathrm{dx}
\\\\
A&={1\over2} \int_{0}^{\pi^2\over4} \sin \left(2\theta \right)  \mathrm{d \theta}
\\&= {1 \over 2 } \int_{0}^{\pi^2\over4}2 \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) \mathrm{d \theta}\\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi^2\over4} \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) \mathrm{d \theta}\\
t:&=\sin(\theta)\\\theta:&0\to{\pi^2\over4}\\t:&0\to \underbrace{\color{red}{\sin \left({\pi^2\over4} \right)}}_{~~\text{=???}~~ }  \\
{\mathrm{dt} \over  \mathrm{d\theta}}&=\cos(\theta)\iff \mathrm{dt}=\mathrm{d\theta}\cos(\theta)\\\\
A&=\int_{0}^{\sin\left(\pi^2\over4\right)}t\,\mathrm{dt}\\
&={1\over2}t^2\bigg|_{0}^{\sin\left(\pi^2\over4\right)}+\mathrm{const}\\&=
{1\over2}\sin\left(\pi^2\over4\right)^2+\mathrm{const}
\end{align} $$

I need your wisdom.

Comment: It's a number.   Just treat it like a constant and move on :)

Comment: Since this is a definite integral, there is no "+ const" at the end. The value of $A$ is $\frac{1}{2}\sin^2 \left(\frac{\pi^2}{4}\right)=0.1948539898\ldots$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the question post mine above, one possible correct form of the solution is $\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(\pi^2\over4\right)$.

Owing to @Alan and @Gary, it is ok to include$~\sin\left(\pi^2\over4\right)~$ inside the form of solution even the concrete value of it can't de guessed.

Moreover the arbitrary constant shouldn't be written inside soln in definite integral(I should have taken rest before I post the question).